# Is that possible to set the active color in jPicker programatically?

Tags: jquery, color-picker

I'm using [jPicker](http://www.digitalmagicpro.com/jPicker/), and I would like to change the active color in my code (I create one instance of jPicker at the beginning, with some default active color).

Is that possible ?

Also, is that possible to make the jPicker window drag-able ? Sometimes, I would like to move the window to other location...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can set the color *after* it's initialized like this:

```
$.jPicker.List[0].color.active.val('rgb', { r: 123, g: 123, b: 123 });
//or hex style:
$.jPicker.List[0].color.active.val('ahex', 'FFFFFFFF'); //last 2 are alpha
```

Where each value is the 0-255 of the color for red, green, and blue.  The dragging there's no built-in support for, but you may be able to use a [jQuery UI `.draggable()`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/) on the panel...not sure what possible conflicts the picker's bindings will have with that.

Comment: Hey Nick, thanks for the answer to my first question! Regarding the second one: I see that in the "jPicker Expandable Example" (http://www.digitalmagicpro.com/jPicker/#Expandable) the color picker window is drag-able. How it is done there ??

Comment: @Misha - Oh you're right, seems it's built-in, are you using the latest version? I don't remember it, so seems it was added in a recent version with any non-inline picker by default.

Comment: I'm using version 1.1.5 (the latest for now). In my case, I don't set `window.expandable` to `true`. Do you think it is still possible to make the window drag-able ? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

As you can see on the page you linked to, you can change the color by adding a `color` argument.

```
$('#colorpicker').jPicker({
    color: {active: '#FFCC00'}
});
```